# XSL stylesheet won't compile

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently trying to learn XML and when I try to convert my XML file to a html file using a stylesheet I just get told that it "could not compile the stylesheet". I don't know if there is a mistake in my stylesheet or what the problem is.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
        <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="invoices">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>acmeTransform</title>
                <style type = "text/css"></style>
            </head><body>
            <h1>Invoices</h1>
            <table>
            <tr bgcolor = "light blue">
                <th align="center">Code</th>
                <th align="center">Date</th>
                <th align="center">Customer Name</th>
                <th align="center">Description</th>
                <th align="center">Value</th>
                <th align="center">Status</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "//invoice" />
            </table>
            </body>
         </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "invoice">
        <tr bgcolor = "light blue">
        <td align="center">Code<xsl:value-of select = "invoice-code"/></td>
        <td align="center">Date<xsl:value-of select = "date"/></td>
        <td align="center">Customer Name<xsl:value-of select = "customer-first-name/customer-surname"/></td>
        <td align="center">Description<xsl:value-of select = "description"/></td>
        <td align="center">Value<xsl:value-of select = "value"/></td>
        <td align="center">Status<xsl:value-of select = "status"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
```

Comment: Where is the closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the xsl:stylesheet closing tag. Try adding this to the end:

`</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: It was there in the markdown source but the code block in the question wasn't indented properly so it didn't show up when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dangling `<xsl:value-of select="title"/>` after your closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` tag, you need to remove that to make the XML well formed.  Apart from that the rest of your stylesheet looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is adding the `<xsl:value-of select="title" />` to a template and then closing the `</xsl:stylesheet>` as  *Ian Roberts* said its not well formed as the `<xsl:value-of select="title" />` is not in the proper place.